# click event to div in list not working on ipad

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I added html to Sencha list row the onClick is working fine on Chrome & Safari on Windows, but click event not working on iPad.
Please let me know any suggestion to make example working on iPad.

Sencha Fiddle Example:
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#MadlC#SPOJb#psFLV

Code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['htmlRow'],
    autoLoad: true,
});

store.add([{ "htmlRow": "<div onclick='func_click1();' style='background:gray;width:70px;float:left'>Click 1</div><div onclick='func_click2()' style='background:yellow;width:70px;float:left'>Click 2</div>" }]);
store.add([{ "htmlRow": "Edt"}]);
store.add([{ "htmlRow": "Jamie"}]);
store.add([{ "htmlRow": "Aaron"}]);
store.add([{ "htmlRow": "Dave"}]);
store.add([{ "htmlRow": "Michael"}]);
store.add([{ "htmlRow": "Abraham"}]);
store.add([{ "htmlRow": "Jay"}]);

//define the application
Ext.application({

    launch: function() {

        Ext.Viewport.add({

            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',

            centered: true,
            hideOnMaskTap: false,

            layout: 'fit',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'list',
                disableSelection:true,  

                itemTpl: '<strong>{htmlRow}</strong>',
                store: store
            }]
        });
    }
});

function func_click1(){
    alert("Why This Click 1 Working on Safari and Google Chrome in Windows, But Not Working on Ipad !");
}
function func_click2(){
    alert("Why This Click 2 Working on Safari and Google Chrome in Windows, But Not Working on Ipad !");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'itemtap' event, you can inspect the 'event' parameter to determine which area of your list item was tapped. In your case, you could do something like this:

- 1) add an id to the two divs in your first row:

  store.add([{ "htmlRow": "`<div id='area1' onclick='func_click1();' style='background:gray;width:70px;float:left'>Click 1</div><div id='area2' onclick='func_click2()' style='background:yellow;width:70px;float:left'>Click 2</div>"` }]);
- 2) in the itemtap listener:

  ```
  itemtap : function(list, index, target, record, event) {
      console.log(event.target.id);
      if (event.target.id=='area1') {
          alert('area1 clicked!');
      }
      if (event.target.id=='area1') {
          alert('area2 clicked!');
      }
  }
  ```

Note that there's much more info in the 'event' param if you need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that 'onclick' cannot be used with tap-input device (I mean touch devices), as it was designed for clicks as the name states.

The proper (ST2) way to get feedback when a row is touched in your list is to listen to the 'itemtap' event of your list:

```
...
items: [{
            xtype: 'list',
            disableSelection:true,  

            itemTpl: '<strong>{htmlRow}</strong>',
            store: store,
            listeners: {
                 itemtap : function(list, index, target, record, event) {
                     // your code here
                 }
        }]
 ...
```

Comment: thanks, i know that code, but i want two listeners for (div1, div2) Not one listener.